# Python: sectioning deque

Tags: python, deque

how to sectioning a `deque` to a portion, somethings like `list_numbers[:5]`?

My dreaming code is like:

```
from collections import deque
deque_num = deque([1, 2, 3])
deque_sectioned = deque_num[:1]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `islice`:

```
from itertools import islice
new_deque = deque(islice(old_deque, 5))
```

Answer (score 0):

One (IMO not particularly elegant) way is to convert the deque to a list, then slice, then convert back to a deque:

```
In [8]: deque(list(deque_num)[:1])
Out[8]: deque([1])
```